# Trying out different machine learning models, the predicted list always turn out the same

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am trying to compare different machine learning models on my data (Austin animal shelter adoption data from data.world). A funny thing happened, the predicted outcome always turn out exactly the same regardless of the models I used (Decision Tree, Logistic Regression, Random Forest).

```
from sklearn import tree
modelDTC_Dog = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='gini')
modelDTC_Dog.fit(df_Dog_X, df_Dog_y)
predictedDTC_Dog = modelDTC_Dog.predict(df_Dog_X)

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
logreg = LogisticRegression()
logreg.fit(df_Dog_X, df_Dog_y)
logreg_predict = logreg.predict(df_Dog_X)

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier 
modelRFC = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, criterion='entropy')
modelRFC.fit(df_Dog_X, df_Dog_y)
predictedRFC = modelRFC.predict(df_Dog_X)
```

predictedDTC_Dog, logreg_predict, and predictedRFC turn out to have the same values. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not an expert on using sklearn. But from the quick look at the code though, you are fitting and predicting from the same data. This can result in complete match. Try to separate out some training data and testing data

Comment: You are getting the same answer because you are feeding an example that models were all trained on. Give them a problem to solve for which they have not already seen the answer.

Comment: Thank you!! Used train_test_split, fitted model with train data, then calculated accuracy for test data. Did this separately with DecisionTree, then LogisticRegression. Got different accuracy values.

Comment: But then perhaps I need to wrap my head around some misconception... Even for the same set of data, shouldn't I get different prediction for the same individual if I use different model, because these models are based on totally different assumptions, theories

Comment: Yes, but you are training and predicting on the same data. So even if the models have completely different assumptions, they will apply that assumptions on the training data to learn about it, and then apply the same assumptions on the prediction data.